# Getting a simplify chart with INDEX-MATCH

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

My problem is that I have different reference codes for the same item (we call it "General Description")

Depending the month of the year we sell one or another, I want a final chart that shows a summary depending the month I chose. Something like the chart below.

Example:

[image]

If the information of the Month is 0, it should give one of the references, e.g.:

- in the case of "Z" it should pick ref "7777" because it has information the next month/s (greater than 0)
- in the case of "a" it should pick ref "9999", since it doesn't have future information (greater than 0) it should consider the last (or closest month date) with information

I tried with Index-Match but couldn't find a solution and I don't know a lot of vba programming which probably is the best way to solve this problem

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Thanks for your fast reply, this is amazing. I tried with bigger data and it's not working at all. In the new image you'll see that in the case of "n" is giving me "n2" .. but should be "n1" because it has information greater than 0 in Apr (same with "q")

[image: Example2]

Answer (score 0):

- The data rows location in output is not exactly same as your screenshot, but you can revised the code to relocate it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iR As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, arrLastMth, vRow, aRow, iCol, vKey
    Dim RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim objDic As Object, objDic2 As Object
    Const START_COL = 3
    ' Load date
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Locate target month
    iCol = Application.Match(Range("B1"), rngData.Rows(1), 0)
    If IsError(iCol) Then Exit Sub
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrLastMth(1 To RowCnt)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 1 To 4)
    iR = 0
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To RowCnt
        If Val(arrData(i, iCol)) > 0 Then
            ' Get row if value > 0 (in target month col)
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrRes(iR, 3) = arrData(i, 3)
            arrRes(iR, 4) = arrData(i, iCol)
            vKey = arrData(i, 1)
            If Not objDic2.exists(vKey) Then
                objDic2(vKey) = CStr(i)
            End If
        Else
            ' Get the last non-zero column for each row
            For j = ColCnt To START_COL Step -1
                If Val(arrData(i, j)) > 0 Then
                    arrLastMth(i) = j
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        ' Consolidate data by "General Desc"
        vKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If Not objDic2.exists(vKey) Then
            If objDic.exists(vKey) Then
                objDic(vKey) = objDic(vKey) & "," & CStr(i)
            Else
                objDic(vKey) = CStr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Loop through data in Dict
    For Each vKey In objDic.Keys
        If Not objDic2.exists(vKey) Then
            aRow = Split(objDic(vKey), ",")
            i = 0: j = 0
            For Each vRow In aRow
                If arrLastMth(CLng(vRow)) > j Then
                    j = arrLastMth(CLng(vRow))
                    i = vRow
                End If
            Next
            ' Load data into output array
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrRes(iR, 3) = arrData(i, 3)
            arrRes(iR, 4) = 0
        End If
    Next
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("J4").Resize(iR, 4).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

---

*Update:*

- Reviewed code is marked by `**`

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo2()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iR As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, arrLastMth, vRow, aRow, iCol, vKey
    Dim RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    Dim objDic As Object, objDic2 As Object
    Const START_COL = 3
    ' Load date
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Locate target month
    iCol = Application.Match(Range("B1"), rngData.Rows(1), 0)
    If IsError(iCol) Then Exit Sub
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrLastMth(1 To RowCnt)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt, 1 To 4)
    iR = 0
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To RowCnt
        If Val(arrData(i, iCol)) > 0 Then
            ' Get row if value > 0 (in target month col)
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrRes(iR, 3) = arrData(i, 3)
            arrRes(iR, 4) = arrData(i, iCol)
            vKey = arrData(i, 1)
            If Not objDic2.exists(vKey) Then
                objDic2(vKey) = CStr(i)
            End If
        Else
            ' Get the last non-zero column for each row
            For j = ColCnt To START_COL Step -1
                If Val(arrData(i, j)) > 0 Then
                    ' ** Change
                    If j > iCol Then
                        arrLastMth(i) = j
                    Else
                        If arrLastMth(i) = 0 Then
                            arrLastMth(i) = j
                        End If
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    ' ** Change End
                End If
            Next
        End If
        ' Consolidate data by "General Desc"
        vKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If Not objDic2.exists(vKey) Then
            If objDic.exists(vKey) Then
                objDic(vKey) = objDic(vKey) & "," & CStr(i)
            Else
                objDic(vKey) = CStr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Loop through data in Dict
    ' ** Change
    Dim bFuture As Boolean ' True - non-zero in future mths
    For Each vKey In objDic.Keys
        If Not objDic2.exists(vKey) Then
            aRow = Split(objDic(vKey), ",")
            i = 0: j = 0
            bFuture = False
            For Each vRow In aRow
                If arrLastMth(CLng(vRow)) > iCol Then
                    bFuture = True
                    j = arrLastMth(CLng(vRow))
                    i = vRow
                End If
            Next
            If bFuture Then
                For Each vRow In aRow
                    If arrLastMth(CLng(vRow)) < j And arrLastMth(CLng(vRow)) > iCol Then
                        j = arrLastMth(CLng(vRow))
                        i = vRow
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                For Each vRow In aRow
                    If arrLastMth(CLng(vRow)) > j Then
                        j = arrLastMth(CLng(vRow))
                        i = vRow
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            ' ** Change End
            ' Load data into output array
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrRes(iR, 3) = arrData(i, 3)
            arrRes(iR, 4) = 0
            'arrRes(iR, 4) = IIf(j > iCol, arrData(i, j), 0)
        End If
    Next
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("Q4").Resize(iR, 4).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @taller, I tried with a bigger amount of information but it seems that there is something missing. I added a new image above

Comment: I have updated the code.